# Sed for replace a substring inside a string with a pattern

Tags: command-line, sed

I am trying to replace a part of a pattern, such as, if I have `col(3,B,14)`, after applying the `sed` command, I would like to get `col(3,B,t14)` which adds the `t` character to the third parameter in the pattern.

I am trying with :

```
s="col(3,B,14)"
echo $s | sed 's/col([0-9],[A-Z],[0-9])/col([0-9],[A-Z],t[0-9])/g'
```

But, it returns the original string.
I would appreciate it if you could give some advice.
Thanks.

Comment: You should use back references in the replacement string: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html

Comment: Thank you FedonKadifeli, yes I follow you advice and I found the solution : echo $s | sed -E 's/col(\(.*),(.*),(.*)\)/col\1,\2,t\3)/g'  using the back references as you suggest. Thank very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem a bit confused about how `sed` works, so I'll go step by step. My "answer" is this:

```
s="col(3,B,14)"; echo $s | sed 's/\(col([0-9],[A-Z],\)/\1t/g'
```

#### Explanation

There are a couple of problems here.

- First, you need a semicolon (`;`) after defining your variable `s`, before `echo`ing it.

  ```
   s="col(3,B,14)"; echo $s
  ```
- Next, `sed` substitution works by `s/pattern/replacement/`, where `pattern` is a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/), but where `replacement` is not. That is, putting something like `[0-9]` in the `replacement` will not represent any digit, but will instead represent the five characters: `[`, `0`, `-`, `9`, and `]`.
- Also, the `/g` at the end is used to keep applying the substitution on a string for every match of the pattern, so if you had a line like:

  ```
  echo hello world | sed 's/o/z/g'
  ```

  then the output would be:

  ```
  hellz wzrld
  ```

  whereas:

  ```
  echo hello world | sed 's/o/z/'
  ```

  would give:

  ```
  hellz world
  ```
- Let's remove your replacement for now:

  ```
  s="col(3,B,14)"; echo $s | sed 's/col([0-9],[A-Z],[0-9])/replacement/g'
  ```

  Turning attention to the regular expression pattern you used, it says "match a string like `col(<single digit>,<uppercase letter>,<single digit>)`". Notice that the last `[0-9]` piece won't match `14`, since `14` is a two-digit number and so your pattern would match `col(3,B,1)`, but will not match `col(3,B,14)`. To match one or more digits, you can use `[0-9][0-9]*`.
- To do the replacement as you want, the best way would be to use a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Capture groups "remember" part of the match for later use. You put `\(` and `\)` around the part of the pattern you want to remember and use `\1` to refer to it later:

  ```
  s="col(3,B,14)"; echo $s | sed 's/\(col([0-9],[A-Z],\)/\1replacement/g'
  ```

  This will match `col(<single digit>,<uppercase letter>,`, so up to and including the point where you want to add a `t`. All of this matched stuff will be put back in the replacement (`\1`) followed by any text you add (in this case we're adding the literal text "replacement"). Any remaining text not matched in the input will be unaffected. The above will output:

  ```
  col(3,B,replacement14)
  ```
- So if we now put a "t" in the `replacement` string:

  ```
  s="col(3,B,14)"; echo $s | sed 's/\(col([0-9],[A-Z],\)/\1t/g'
  ```

  we get:

  ```
  col(3,B,t14)
  ```

If you want to learn `sed` well, I can recommend an excellent tutorial: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: The mattb answer is really great, but there's one mistake. The output after:
```
s="col(3,B,14)"; echo $s | sed 's/\(col([0-9],[A-Z],\)/\1replacement/g'
```
shoudn't be:
```
col(3,B,1replacement4)
```
but:
```
col(3,B,replacement14)
```

Comment: Instead of `[0-9][0-9]*` you could also use `[0-9]+` to match numbers with one digit or more. `+` means "match one or more of the preceding token", whereas `*` means "match zero or more of the preceding token".

Comment: @vaktare95 Fixed! thank you!